# Regex extract between trible double quotes and newlines

Tags: regex, vbscript

For example i want to parse python file with text between triple double quotes and make html table from this text.

Text block for example like that

```
"""
Replaces greater than operator ('>') with 'NOT BETWEEN 0 AND #'
Replaces equals operator ('=') with 'BETWEEN # AND #'

Tested against:
    * Microsoft SQL Server 2005
    * MySQL 4, 5.0 and 5.5
    * Oracle 10g
    * PostgreSQL 8.3, 8.4, 9.0

Requirement:
    * Microsoft Access

Notes:
    * Useful to bypass weak and bespoke web application firewalls that
      filter the greater than character
    * The BETWEEN clause is SQL standard. Hence, this tamper script
      should work against all (?) databases

>>> tamper('1 AND A > B--')
'1 AND A NOT BETWEEN 0 AND B--'
>>> tamper('1 AND A = B--')
'1 AND A BETWEEN B AND B--'
"""
```

Html table must be simple table contains 5 columns

1. Column everything between `"""` and `\n if new line is empty`
2. Column everything between `Tested against:` and `\n if new line is empty` or `Requirement:` and `\n if new line is empty`
3. Column everything between `Notes:` and `\n if new line is empty`
4. Column everything between `>>>` and `\n`
5. Column everything between `4 column end` and `\n`

So result must be:

1. Replaces greater than operator ('>') with 'NOT BETWEEN 0 AND #'
   Replaces equals operator ('=') with 'BETWEEN # AND #'
2. - Microsoft SQL Server 2005

     - MySQL 4, 5.0 and 5.5
     - Oracle 10g
     - PostgreSQL 8.3, 8.4, 9.0

     or

     - Microsoft Access
3. - Useful to bypass weak and bespoke web application firewalls that
       filter the greater than character
   - The BETWEEN clause is SQL standard. Hence, this tamper script
       should work against all (?) databases
4. tamper('1 AND A > B--')
   tamper('1 AND A = B--')
5. '1 AND A NOT BETWEEN 0 AND B--'
   '1 AND A BETWEEN B AND B--'

What kind of syntax can i use to extract that? 
I will use VBScript.RegExp .

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
txt = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.py").ReadAll

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = """([^""]*)"""
re.Global = True

For Each m In re.Execute(txt)
  WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0)
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is quite broad, so I'll just outline a way to deal with this. Otherwise I'd have to write the whole script for you, which isn't going to happen.

1. Extract everything between the docquotes. Use a regular expression like this to extract the text between the docquotes:

   ```
   Set re1 = New RegExp
   re1.Pattern = """""""([\s\S]*?)"""""""

   For Each m In re1.Execute(txt)
     docstr = m.SubMatches(0)
   Next
   ```

   Note that you need to set the `re.Global` to `True` if you have more than 1 docstring in your file and want all of them processed. Otherwise you'll get just the first match.
2. Remove leading and trailing whitespace with a second regular expression:

   ```
   Set re2 = New RegExp
   re2.Pattern = "^\s*|\s*$"
   re2.Global  = True  'find all matches

   docstr = re2.Replace(docstr, "")
   ```

   You can't use `Trim` for this, because the function handles only spaces, not other whitespace.
3. Either split the string at 2+ consecutive line breaks to get the doc sections, or use another regular expression to extract them:

   ```
   Set re3 = New RegExp
   re3.Pattern = "([\s\S]*?)\r\n\r\n" +
                 "Tested against:\r\n([\s\S]*?)\r\n\r\n" +
                 ...

   For Each m In re3.Execute(txt)
     descr  = m.SubMatches(0)
     tested = m.SubMatches(1)
     ...
   Next
   ```

Continue breaking down the sections until you have the elements you want to display. Then build the HTML from these elements.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Excellent explanation.